# Cannot connect to EC2 Instance either SSH or EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I got stuck when connecting to my EC2 instance. I did try both SSH with .pem file or EC2 Instance Connect. Everything was ok in the first time. But after that, something went wrong.

I tried to terminate my instance and launch new one once. But the new instance get this error too. Too weird.

This is error text when connecting via EC2 Instance Connect.

[image]

And this is log when connecting via SSH with verbose

[image]

And this is the security rules for my instance

[image]

Does anyone know solution for this case? Thank in advance.

-- UPDATE 1--

Result after run Reachability Analyzer with source (gateway) and destination (instance)

[image]

Comment: I tried connecting and go the same result. It is basically saying that the networking configuration is not permitting access to the instance. Your Security Group seems fine, so it is something else -- perhaps it was launched in a Private subnet instead of a Public subnet? Is there a firewall (ufw) running on the instance? You could try the [VPC Reachability Analyzer - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/reachability/what-is-reachability-analyzer.html) to see if the Internet Gateway can reach the instance.

Comment: Hi, I have just updated my question with result from Reachability Analyzer. The result is success. Does it mean that instance is in Public subnet? Thank a lot

Comment: That suggests that the problem is inside your instance. Can you tell us how you launched the instance? Did you do anything on the instance before it went bad (eg installed some software)?

Comment: Yeah. I have installed node and nginx for deploying single-spa applications. That's all.

Comment: When you say "the new instance get this error too", is that immediately or only after installing the software?

Comment: IIrc, this erros just happened after setup nginx and its config (everything is okay but the next time connect to instance)

Comment: In that case, it is related to something that is happening during the install, such as `ufw` being activated.

Answer (score -1):

yes, all problems in ssh is in the user name inside of the instance, So follow these steps to solve your problem:

> 1. go to ec2 dashboard and check what is the user name inside your
>    instance.
> 2. make new connect with instance and download new file ".pem" from
>    ec2 dashboard.
> 3. make new file and named it "config" in local machine with this
>    path :

```
~/.ssh/config
```

> 4. write this code below in your config file

```
# Enter the alias of the ECS instance to connect to the instance by using an SSH key pair. 
Host ec2
#Enter the public IP address of the instance. 
HostName <public IP>
#Enter the port number. The default port number is 22. 
Port 22
#Enter the logon account. 
User <put the user name you found in your instance>
#Enter the address of the .pem private key file on your PC. 
IdentityFile <~/Desktop/myservice.pem>
```

> 5. if you want to ssh it just do like this

```
ssh ec2
```

Comment: Hi, how can I make new connection with the instance? Could you give me more details on step 2? Thank a lot

Comment: yes follow this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/create-key-pairs.html#having-ec2-create-your-key-pair